# Updating parameter with button on click and unclick

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 4 buttons on my webpage, each having a value. So depending on which buttons are pressed/clicked in the webpage I need the parameter "Buttonvals" to be modified in the url accordingly, as these values will be used as filters for my SQL query.

Eg if buttons 1 2 and 4 are selected

the url must be: url?buttonvals=value1|value2|value4. 
Please suggest how I go about doing this. Please provide code if possible as I am still new to Javascript and php

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="item1" value="value1"> value1 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item2" value="value2">  value2 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item3" value="value3">  value3 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="item4" value="value4">  value4 <br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">




  the url must become something like   url?buttonvals=value1|value2|value4
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Share your HTML also

Comment: Please provide some example HTML that we can use to help you (easier and faster)

Comment: sounds like you actually want checkboxes, not buttons.

Comment: As @Jeff told I would use hidden checkboxes and trigger the values by the buttons.

Comment: I have added the html :) yes checkboxes are what I was looking for

Comment: use the same name for related checkboxes "buttonvals". upon submit url will be  url?buttonvals=value1&buttonvals=value2 ... you can get enumerable values in the backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi R P I have a solution for you.

Your HTML Code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item1" value="value1" onclick="setUrlParams(this)"> value1 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="item2" value="value2" onclick="setUrlParams(this)">  value2 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="item3" value="value3" onclick="setUrlParams(this)">  value3 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="item4" value="value4" onclick="setUrlParams(this)">  value4 <br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

JS Code

```
   function setUrlParams($obj){

  var myButtonClasses = $obj.classList;

 if (myButtonClasses.contains("chbox-clicked")) {

    myButtonClasses.remove("chbox-clicked");

 }else{
   myButtonClasses.add("chbox-clicked");
 }


  //now get all selcted classes
  var valueStr = "";
var chboxCheckd  = document.getElementsByClassName('chbox-clicked');
for (var i = 0; i < chboxCheckd.length; ++i) {
    var item = chboxCheckd[i];  
    valueStr = valueStr+item.value+"|";
}
  var finalurl = window.location.href;
  if( finalurl.indexOf('?') >= 0){
    finalurl = finalurl+"&buttonvals="+valueStr.slice(0, -1);
   }else{
    finalurl = finalurl+"?buttonvals="+valueStr.slice(0, -1); 
   }
  //var finalurl = "http://abc.xyz/buttonvals="+valueStr.slice(0, -1);
  console.log(finalurl);
  //window.history.replaceState(null, null, finalurl);
  //window.location.href = finalurl
}
```

Well uncomment replacestate line to change location without reloading page. Or uncomment last line to reload the page with url.

Currently it's only printing on console. Not allowed here on JS editor also so.

[DEMO](https://jsbin.com/nigavic/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Hi, This works well :) but if there are other parameters in the url this will remove those parameters how do I fix that? :)

Comment: I have edited the code and jsbin also. Check now. @RP

Comment: Nope. Its printing https://null.jsbin.com/runner?buttonvals=value1|value2|value3|value4 Check on js bin. @RP

Comment: If you want to retain values then store checked checkbox value somewhere and do reverse to show checked. @RP